# How do I change the default name for a new folder?

Tags: files, filemanager, thunar

When I create a new folder in the Thunar file-manager via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, a folder appears. The default name which is suggested is `New folder`. I like to change that suggestion to `ideas` or `drawer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without recompile Thunar. If you're really interested, then tell me about it.

---

Here are the first steps:

Download the source code via

```
mkdir -p ~/src
cd ~/src
apt-get source thunar
sudo apt-get build-dep thunar
cd thunar-1.6.6
```

Find the occurences of `New Folder` via

```
grep -r 'New Folder' *
```

make your changes and recompile.

For clarification, in my case, the command `sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b` was not working to build a deb package. Therefore the good old way

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: @muru Thanks for the edit. I have no idea why I wanted to use `sudo` for the command: `apt-get source thunar`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Now I have more than a idea how it work. But i'm not familiar enough with this building own packages stuff. So a task for a longer linux session...